# Share to Google+ After Login With Google SignIn

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-plus, google-signin

Before the Google SignIn API this is how I shared an image:

```
let shareBuilder = GPPShare.sharedInstance().nativeShareDialog()
shareBuilder.setPrefillText(someText)
shareBuilder.attachImage(anImage)
shareBuilder.open()
```

But now, after I sign in with the new API and try to share I get an error that says: "*User must be signed in to use the native sharebox*"

How can I fix this error?

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google+ SDK is deprecated.If you want to share to google +,you can only their way [Basic sharing without signing in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share).However,I don't know how to share an image within their newest way.